# --exclude-dir option in grep does not work as expected

Tags: shell, grep

I'm trying to exclude multiple directories when using `grep` as in the following command

```
grep -r --exclude-dir={folder1, folder2} 'foo'
```

However, an error is raised `grep: foo: No such file or directory`. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with `--exclude-dir` option since the command below works as expected

```
grep -r 'foo'
```

How can I use `--exclude-dir` option correctly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--exclude-dir` flag of GNU grep takes a *glob* expression as an argument. The glob expression with more than items then becomes a brace expansion sequence which is expanded by the shell.

The expansion involves words separated by a comma character and doesn't like spaces between the words. So ideally it should have been

```
--exclude-dir={folder1,folder2}
```

You can see this as a simple brace expansion in your shell by running

```
echo {a,b}   # produces 'a b'
echo {a, b}  # this doesn't undergo expansion by shell
echo --exclude-dir={folder1, folder2}
--exclude-dir={folder1, folder2}
```

so, your original command becomes

```
grep -r '--exclude-dir={folder1,' 'folder2}' foo
```

i.e. the exclude-dir takes a unexpanded glob expansion string as `{folder1,'` and `'folder2}'` becomes the content that you are trying to search for, leaving `foo` as an unwanted extra argument, which the argparser of `grep` doesn't like throwing a command line parse error.

Remember brace expansion is a feature of the shell (e.g. `bash`), and not `grep`. In shells that don't support the feature, putting directories between `{..}` will be treated literally and might not work desirably.